# JMeter - different HTTP request for different number of threads in the same thread group

Tags: jmeter

I am load-testing a web application. I have recorded 5 different test scenarios using HTTP test script recorder under the same thread group.
I want to run the script with 5 threads, different thread for each request.
For Ex:
5 HTTP Requests in the same Thread Group.
5 Users. Different user for each HTTP request
1st user 1st HTTP request, 2nd user 2nd HTTP request... 5th user 5th HTTP request.

How to implement this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your explicit question would be easier to spot when terminated by a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) for this and put [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) and  [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combinatino as the "Switch Value"

[image]

This way each user will pick up the relevant Switch Controller's child:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)